# I'd like to Get a numeric value from cell, say B52, use that value as a cell ref elsewhere in my worksheet so I can place an alternative value into it

Tags: excel

I'm looking to take a numeric value from a cell in the lower section of my sheet, lets say B52 and it contains a 3. I now want to place a value of 1 into another cell within my worksheet using that retrieved value as the new cell ref, say B3.
B52 contains a 7 then place a 1 in B7

Hope that makes sense....Anyone

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you looking for a formula (in `B3` and/or `B7`, for VBA-code that writes a value of 1 into `B3` and/or `B7`???

Comment: I thought I'd made it perfectly clear but here goes another attempt.  I have a column of numbers bottom half of sheet.  Depending on the value in each of these cells I want to place a 1 in the same column but in the upper half of the sheet in cell(value).  I guess a formula is what I'm looking for if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your question makes perfect sense and it is possible to do this, but I only do this using VBA, as follows:

```
sub test()
  Range("B" & Range("B52").Value).Value = 1
end sub
```

I heavily doubt this can be done with normal Excel: you can write the following formula in all cells in column "B":

```
=IF(ROW()=B$52,1,"")
```

Obviously you can't do this in cell "B52", or you cause a circular reference :-)